# Jersey - not scanning for resources?

Tags: tomcat, logging, jersey

I have a Jersey application deployed as a WAR in Tomcat. I get 404s for all my resources, and I'm trying to find out why.

Since I've enabled Jersey logging, I see a log message indicating that Jersey is initializing:

```
INFO:   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR 
+INFO:       Deploying web application archive myApp.war 
INFO:   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler initialize 
+INFO:       Initiating Jersey application, version Jersey: 2.3.1 2013-09-27 07:50:09... [.logger.j2se.BizManagerHandler]
```

Judging by other SO posts, I would expect to see a log like this as the next line:

```
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
    com.xxx.restful
```

I do not see this log, nor any log showing found resources - so I am not confident that the scan is occurring.

The `web.xml` within `myApp.war` contains this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>My Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.example.MyConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.example.myApp.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
        <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
        <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.feature.Trace</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.feature.Debug</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

I assume the log I *do* see is evidence that this servlet element is being deployed.

Is there a reason I'm missing why either:

- The scan isn't occurring?
- The scan is occurring, but not being logged?

Thanks

Comment: Can you list some of the 404 URIs and the annotations that should have made them work? Where's this servlet mapped?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying to configure Jersey 2 application (package prefix `org.glassfish.jersey`) with Jersey 1 properties (package prefix `com.sun.jersey`). This is not supported at the moment. Take a look at the article [Registering Resources and Providers in Jersey 2](http://blog.dejavu.sk/2013/11/19/registering-resources-and-providers-in-jersey-2/) which is explaining how to achieve such a thing in Jersey 2. There are also references to supported properties.

Note: You won't see log message informing you about found resources/providers in Jersey 2.